# Como alterar a página .html automaticamente a partir de um tempo pré determinado?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Possuo um sistema para **exibição de conteúdos** e necessito que **a partir de um tempo pré determinado** a minha **página** `.html` **altere para um outro conteúdo (outra página) automaticamente**.

**NOTA:**

> O dispositivo para exibir o site não conterá dispositivos de entrada como mouse, é necessário que a partir do carregamento da página a função seja executada.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

 <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.png"/>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"> 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>.:: Painel Cirurgias ::.</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/inside.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/select2.css "/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootbox.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/select2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/meio.mask.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
 <!-- <link href="css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

</head>

<body class="gradient">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <center>
    <br>
    <a href="index.php"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
   </center>
  </div>
  <div class="row">

<?php

include_once('db_functions.php');

ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');

$id = isset($_GET['id'])?$id=$_GET['id']: NULL;
$id = isset($_POST['id'])?$id=$_POST['id']: NULL;

$con = dbConnect();

?>

<div class="content well pull-left span12">

 <div class="row">
  <div class="span12">
   <?php

       include('paginator.php');

       $page = isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:1;

    $busca = isset($_GET['busca'])?$_GET['busca']:null;

    $painels = findPainels($con,$busca);

    $painelsPag = getPageElements($painels,$page,11);

   ?>

   <?php if($painels):?>
    <table class="table table-striped">
     <thead>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Data</th>      
      <th>Hora</th>
      <th>Paciente</th>
      <th>Tipo</th>
      <th>Hospital</th>
      <th>Médico</th>
      <th>Convênio</th>
      <th>Cliente</th>
      <th>Intermediário</th>       
      <th></th>
     </thead>
     <tbody>

      <?php foreach ($painelsPag as $painel):

          if ($painel["Cliente"] === 'ORTHOSEVEN'){        
        $painel["Cliente"] = '<span style="background:orange">'.$painel["Cliente"].'</span>';
       }

       elseif ($painel["Cliente"] === 'BM9 IMPLANTES'){
        $painel["Cliente"] = '<span style="background:#1E90FF">'.$painel["Cliente"].'</span>';
       }

        if ($painel["Intermediario"] === 'ORTHOSEVEN'){        
         $painel["Intermediario"] = '<span style="background:orange">'.$painel["Intermediario"].'</span>';
        }

        elseif ($painel["Intermediario"] === 'BM9 IMPLANTES'){
         $painel["Intermediario"] = '<span style="background:#1E90FF">'.$painel["Intermediario"].'</span>';
        }

         else {

          $cor = "#1E90FF";
         }

      ?>
       <tr bgcolor="<?=$cor="#66CDAA"?>" class="<?=$painel['id']?null:'muted'?>" data-id="<?=$painel['id']?>">
       <tr bgcolor="<?=$cor?>" data-id="<?=$painel['id']?>">
        <td data-title="id"><strong><?=$painel['id']?></td></strong>
        <td data-title="Status"><strong><?=$painel['Status'];?></td></strong>
        <td data-title="Data"><strong><?=date('d/m/Y',strtotime($painel['Data']))?></td></strong>
        <td data-title="Hora"><strong><?=$painel['Hora']?></td></strong>
        <td data-title="Paciente"><strong><?=$painel['Paciente']?></td></strong>
        <td data-title="Tipo"><strong><?=$painel['Subtipo_Cirurgia']?></td></strong>
        <td data-title="Hospital"><strong><?=$painel['Hospital']?></td></strong>
        <td data-title="Medico"><strong><?=$painel['Medico']?></td></strong>
        <td data-title="Convenio"><strong><?=$painel['Convenio']?></td></strong>
        <td data-title="Cliente"><strong><?=$painel['Cliente']?></td></strong>
        <td data-title="Intermediario"><strong><?=$painel['Intermediario']?></td></strong>
       </tr>   
      <?php endforeach;?>
     </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php printPaginator($painels,$page,11);?>
   <?php else:?>
   <?php endif;?>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<?php include("base.php"); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.reload(1);
    }, 50000);
});
 
</script>

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<?php include("base.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Ao invés de usar `window.location.reload(1);` você fazer um form submit. Ex. `var form = $('<form method="get" action="apropriapagina.php"> <input type="hidden" name="page" value="2"> </form>) $('body').append( form) form.submit()`

Comment: @Bah essa mudança de página teria que ocorrer a partir de que evento? Por exemplo: Clicar no submit do formulário, ao passar o mouse em algum local, quando a página já estiver carregada?

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse arquivo aqui http://twixar.me/wJ1n, É possível atualizar a pagina sem precisar de javascript

Comment: @Bah respondi a sua pergunta, era isto o que realmente desejava?

Comment: Cara vc quer que de tempo em tempo a página seja encaminhada para outra página, tipo fazendo um refresh com outro conteúdo é isso?

Comment: @Bah a minha resposta esta correta para você? O que ficou faltando?

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa sem o uso de JavaScript é com a meta tag Refresh, com ela vc pode dizer quanto tempo vc quer que o documento espere antes de ser encaminhado para outra página, vc pode ler mais aqui https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#statedef-http-equiv-refresh

Funcionaria assim, imagina que vc tem tres página `(p1.html, p2.html e p3.html)`, e a cada 10 segundos (10s) vc quer que uma página seja redirecionada para outra. Tipo, fica 10s na p1.html, depois vai para p2.html e fica mais 10s, depois vai para p3.html etc...

Para fazer isso dentro da tag `<head>` de cada documento vc precisa colocar uma `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; p*.html">`, repare que no `content="10;` o 10 se refere aos segundos que vai ficar na página antes de encaminhar para a outra.

Logo vc teria essa estrutura na **p1.html**

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; p2.html">
</head>
```

Isso vai fazer que depois que a `p1.html` carregar, 10 segundo depois vai te encaminhar para `p2.html`

E esse mesmo modelo se repetiria no `<head>` da `p2.html e p3.html` só mudando o direcionamento para página que deseja, e colocando o tempo que quer em cada página

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo o seu raciocínio onde ao adentrar a determinada página `.html`, a partir de um tempo pré-determinado o "usuário" será encaminhado para outra página `.html` e vise-versa.

Para isto você precisa utilizar alguns **eventos** e **métodos** do javascript, os quais são:

- [Evento DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)
- [Método setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)
- [Método Window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

**DOMContentLoaded**

> O evento `DOMContentLoaded` é acionado quando todo o HTML foi completamente carregado e analisado, sem aguardar pelo CSS, imagens, e subframes para encerrar o carregamento. Um evento muito diferente - `load` - deve ser usado apenas para detectar uma página completamente carregada. É um engano comum as pessoas usarem `load` quando `DOMContentLoaded` seria muito mais apropriado.
>
> **Observação:** Javascript Síncrono pausa a análise do DOM.

**setTimeOut()**

> O `setTimeout()` é um método do  `WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope` (e successor do `Window.setTimeout()`), onde define um temporizador que executa uma função ou parte específica do código quando o temporizador expira.
>
> **Observação:** A passagem de parâmetros adicionais para a função na primeira sintaxe não funciona no Internet Explorer 9 e abaixo. Se você quiser ativar essa funcionalidade nesse navegador, deverá usar um `polyfill` (consulte a seção `Polyfill` ).

**Window.location**

> O `Window.location` é uma propriedade de leitura que retorna um objeto Location com informações de localização do documento atual. Embora `Window.location` seja apenas um objeto de leitura de localização, você pode também atribuir uma `DOMString` para ele. Isto significa que você pode trabalhar com `location` como se fosse uma string na maioria dos casos: `location = 'http://www.exemplo.com'` é um sinônimo de `location.href = 'http://www.exemplo.com'`.

**Abaixo segue um exemplo de funcionamento, onde o cenário é o seguinte:**

Você possui **duas (2) páginas** (`pagOne.html` e `pagTwo.html`), um **evento** de **verificação** se o `.html` já foi **totalmente carregado** (`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"..)`) e uma **função** para alterar a **página a partir de um tempo pré determinado, utilizando os métodos citados** (`alterarPagina()` + `setTimeOut()` + `window.location.replace()`);

**PagOne.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Página UM</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="color: red;">VOCÊ ESTÁ NA PÁGINA UM</h1>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
            alert("DOM completamente carregado e analisado");
            alterarPagina(1000);
        });

        function alterarPagina(timer) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                alert("O TEMPO ACABOU!");
                window.location.replace('pagTwo.html');
            }, timer);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PageTwo.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Página DOIS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="color: red;">VOCÊ ESTÁ NA PÁGINA DOIS</h1>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
            alert("DOM completamente carregado e analisado");
            alterarPagina(1000);
        });

        function alterarPagina(timer) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                alert("O TEMPO ACABOU!");
                window.location.replace('pagOne.html');
            }, timer);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**NOTA:**

> Tome cuidado com os eventos, sugiro que leia a documentação dos mesmos para verificar com mais detalhes o seu funcionamento.

Comment: Mas o problema maior é que as paginas não são fixas, no meu select está para exibir os registros nos ultimo 60 dias, pode ser que gere 10 paginas ou 7 pag. Ai vai variar e alem de mudar de pagina terei de colocar um reflesh na tela a cada 1 min.  Seria essa minha grande dificuldade.